# Size mismatch of structs in arrays. sizeof() vs sys.getsizeof()

Tags: arrays, pointers, cython, mesh

I was trying to do some structs in [Cython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cython) to create a custom mesh format and was checking out Vertex structures fitting into arrays.

The code itself follows as:

```python
%%cython
cimport cython
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from cython cimport sizeof, NULL
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import sys

ctypedef np.float64_t dtype_t

# The first layer simplex. A point with 2 coordinates
ctypedef struct Vertex:
    double x
    double y

# Unit test
cpdef Vertex create_vertex(double x_coord, double y_coord):
    cdef Vertex v
    v.x = x_coord
    v.y = y_coord
    return v


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef Vertex* alloc_varr(int size):
    cdef Vertex* array = <Vertex*>malloc(size * sizeof(Vertex))
    cdef size_t i
    for i in range(size):
        array[i] = create_vertex(np.random.rand(), np.random.rand())
    return array

cdef int size = 3
cdef Vertex* arr_ptr = alloc_varr(size)

print(sizeof(Vertex))

for i in range(size):
    print(arr_ptr[i])

    print(sizeof(&arr_ptr[i]))

free(arr_ptr)
```

Now the last *for* loop is to test the size.

The output is as follows.

```
16
{'x': 0.9773117249104714, 'y': 0.11605063449326936}
8
{'x': 0.15629620742359918, 'y': 0.6968917513416493}
8
{'x': 0.13464473583592163, 'y': 0.40488504180083373}
8
```

Which is unexpected because arr_ptr[i] has the Vertex as content which itself is 16 bytes. But its sizeof() shows 8 bytes on the whole contents of arr_ptr[i] which is supposed to be 16.

Why?

And it gets even wilder if I do not dereference arr_ptr[i] and use sys.getsizeof() as the following syntax:

```python
for i in range(size):
    print(arr_ptr[i])

    print(sys.getsizeof(arr_ptr[i]))
```

Gives

```
16
{'x': 0.40535087801702774, 'y': 0.45886973881535087}
232
{'x': 0.8044147575449122, 'y': 0.7465885954913871}
232
{'x': 0.5648944630679318, 'y': 0.4760429822956501}
232
```

232 bytes for arr_ptr[0/1/2] which is even more odd.
What is going here. Could somebody explain? Since size management of the mesh is kind of crucial.

Also, why are the elements of *arr_ptr[]* of dictionary type instead of our custom Vertex type?

Comment: I haven't used `cython` much, but normally `C` struct are maped onto `numpy` structured arrays, for example `dtype([('x', 'float'), ('y', 'float')])`.  This has 2 floats, so itemsize is 16.  And element, unboxed, will use those 16 bytes for data, but `getsizeof` will be the record overhead over a round 100-200 bytes.

Comment: @hpaulj that is such an ugly way of doing it.
In my case they are mapped as a dictionary so i have an array of dicts which is weird

Comment: An array of dicts will be an array of pointers, each referencing a dict.  `getsizeof` is nearly useless when looking at things with object references.

Comment: `sys.getsizeof({'a':12.231, 'b':34.24})` is 232. `sys.getsizeof(np.record((12.231, 34.24), dtype=[('a',float),('b',float)]))` is 80.

Comment: No - the conversion from C struct to dict only happens when you try to pass a C struct to a Python function (like `print` or `sys.sizeof`).

Comment: Also `&arr_ptr[i]` is of type `Vertex*` (thus a pointer and of size 8 on your system) and not of type `Vertex` (which has size 16).

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the info @ead i just realized the & for the pointer reference and if you remove it you get the correct 16 Bytes for the whole contents of `arr_ptr[i]`

@DavidW thanks for the info too